# How to renew Provisioning Profile for iOS Enterprise Dev Licence

Tags: ios, xcode

I got this message on the client iPad (and mine):

> Your provisioning "xxxyyy" is about to expire in 28 days.

My context:

- I use a Enterprise Dev Licence.
- I renew it on december 2011
- On the iOS Dev Portal, for my licence, it says "expire april 2012" (I'm pretty sure it was normal, because need manual renew each 90 days)
- I can see that all the distribution certificate profile linked to that licence are tagged "expire Apr 20, 2012" (this fit what iPad says)

The situation:

- I have a lot of Enterprise apps distributed to client, which are all linked to the same Provisioning Profile (expiring in 28 days)
- I see NO option to just (to simply) renew my Enterprise dev certificate
- I see the option to download or revoke my Enterprise dev certificate
- I'm pretty sure "revoke" and create a new one can solve BUT I just can't break the current app  (linked to the actual Provisioning Profile).

Client just can't have to re-download apps.

I can also wait the 28 days, and I will probably get the "renew" button.

But client is still bugged with the xx days left.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4 open `Organizer` (right top corner of main window), then select `Provisioning Profiles` in `Library` section from menu list at left window side. You will see your profile and buttons "new", "import", "export" and "refresh" on bottom side of window. Click on `Refresh` and type your developer login & password. After processing your profile will be updated (maybe a clone profile will appear, then delete old expiring one).

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your help 
I've try, still not work:
"Creation date 11-05-03, Expiration date: 12-04-19"